# check if multiple bits are set with std::bitset<8>

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset

Whats the best approach to check if multiple bits are set with bitset<8>?
For example &-operation with uint8_t variable ?
`(bitsetvariable & flag) == 0` or is something like this possible
`bitsetvariable.test(std::bitset<8>(flag))`
?

Comment: You'd need to define what "compare" means in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `bitset` class has a [`to_ulong` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong) that can convert the bits to an `unsigned long`.

```
if (bitsetvariable.to_ulong() == flag)
```

Comment: Perhaps OP wants `if ((bitsetvariable & flag).to_ulong() == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to use the `all/any/none`; check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/all_any_none)!

If you need to verify a specific *ID* the solution is to use `test` ([doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/test))